# Ruby on Rails if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

I want to make an if statement for my rails project because I have a users page with all the information of the user like avatar, bio, website .etc I want to make it so that if the user does not have an avatar then i will display a default picture, same for the other things.

Comment: Why don't you use the inbuilt if statement?

Comment: @Jayram I am doing a tutorial I dont know what you mean. How do I do that.

Comment: @Priti: this question is too generic, that's why he's getting downvotes.

Comment: I think this is extremely elementary. It sounds like OP should spend some time learning Ruby or perhaps even control structures, before ventoring into Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a completely elementary conditional.

```
<% if @user.avatar.present? %>
  <%= image_tag(@user.avatar.url) %>
<% else %>
  <%= image_tag('path/to/default.png') %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are using ERB you can do something similar:

```
<% if @user.image.nil? %>
  <%= image_tag('default_image_path') %>
<% else %>
  <%= image_tag(@user.image) %>
<% end %>
```

If you are using something like [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) it's even easier, you can set the default url for the image, directly there.
For all other fields, you may do the same:

```
<% if @user.bio.blank? %>
  No Bio available
<% else %>
  <%= @user.bio %>
<% end %>
```

Nothing special, as you can see.

Comment: Ha ha :).. I agree with you.. I just visited @jayram profile,, There I found the line.. and it is a *true line*... :) I didn't comment for OP's post.